# sql oracle группировка

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос, oracle11g

Понимаю, что странный запрос, я такого не видел, но нужно вынести в бд группировку для оптимизации отчёта, и, например, с такими данными:

```
create table person(id number, name varchar2(10), data varchar2(100));
insert into person(id, name, data) values(1, 'sasha', 'qweqweqwe');
insert into person(id, name, data) values(2, 'sasha', 'werwerw');
insert into person(id, name, data) values(3, 'dima', 'asdasdasd');
insert into person(id, name, data) values(4, 'dima', 'zxczxczxc');
insert into person(id, name, data) values(5, 'dima', 'dfgdfgdfg');
```

Получить такой результат:

```
sasha   qweqweqwe
        werwerw
dima    asdasdasd
        zxczxczxc
        dfgdfgdfg
```

То есть чтобы как бы distinct, но для одного группирумого поля. Всю голову поломал, ничего придумать не могу. Версия 11g. Уточню суть. Сам запрос к бд выполняется быстро, но отчёт из-за группировки данных (15 тысяч строк) строится минут 20. Если группировку (не group by) в отчёте убрать и сделать её сразу в запросе, то на скорость запроса не должно сильно повлиять, зато отчёт будет собираться быстрее

Comment: Обычно это решается на уровне отчета (галка в табличке, "скрывать повторы в столбце")

Comment: А где группировка?  И что такое: _нужно вынести в бд группировку для оптимизации отчёта_?

Comment: Получать такой результат с помощью SQL можно, но неправильно.

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: @СашаБезгин Ваше дополнение к сожалению не улучшило понимание вопроса. Какую _группировку (не group by)_, из какого отчёта вы убираете?  Добавте пожалуйста ваш запрос и больше деталей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id, 
                     name, 
                     data, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY data) rn 
              FROM person )
SELECT CASE WHEN rn = 1
            THEN name
            ELSE ''
            END name,
       data
FROM cte
ORDER BY cte.name, rn;
```

или

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LAG(name) OVER (ORDER BY name, data) = name
            THEN ''
            ELSE name
            END name,
       data
FROM person
ORDER BY person.name, data;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bb8543b31dd7a953aff5eaeef34a1dd0)

Answer (score 2):

Ожидаемый результат можно получить, например, так:

```sql
break on name 
select name, data from person order by name desc, id;

NAME       DATA            
---------- ----------------
sasha      qweqweqwe       
           werwerw         
dima       asdasdasd       
           zxczxczxc       
           dfgdfgdfg
```

Comment: *ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement* ... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0e114f16366e883814d0bb44b702368a

Comment: @Akina Ага, а результат я из вопроса скопировал ;) Вы это хотели сказать?